# using `plotmath` to display combination of subscript and `[ ]`

Tags: r, parsing, ggplot2, expression, plotmath

I want to create a plot where I want to display a mean value and confidence intervals for this mean value. To do so, I am using `plotmath`. Here is something I have done that *works*-

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(cyl), wt)) + geom_boxplot() +
  labs(
    title = "Mean weight:",
    subtitle = parse(text = paste(
      "list(~italic(mu)==", 3.22, ",", "CI[95~'%'] ", "(", 2.87, ",", 3.57, "))",
      sep = ""
    ))
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But this is *not* what I actually want. The format in which I instead want to display these results is the following-

[image]

So there are two things I can't seem to figure out how to do using `plotmath`:

1. `95 %` should instead be `95%`
2. Use `[` instead of `(`

How can I do this?

**P.S.** It is important, for reasons to complicated to explain here, for me to have `list` inside the `paste` function because I want to save these expressions as a `character`-type column in a dataframe. This is why I haven't accepted the two solutions provided below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution keeps list and paste.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(cyl), wt)) + geom_boxplot() +
  labs(
    title = "Mean weight:",
    subtitle = parse(text = paste(
      "list(~italic(mu)==", 3.22, ",", "CI[95*'%'] ", "*'['*", 2.87, ",", 3.57, "*']')",
      sep = ""
    ))
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the formula shown:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(cyl), wt)) + geom_boxplot() +
  labs(
    title = "Mean weight:",
    subtitle = ~italic(mu) == 3.22*', '*"CI"[95*'%']*group('[',2.87*','*3.57,']')
  )
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer a solution that doesn't change the code specified in the question though. I want to use `list` + `paste` because I am saving these expressions as columns of type of `character`.

Comment: Just define the same expression as a character string in which case you can paste it together from elements in any way you like.  `subtitle <- "italic(mu) == 3.22*', '*'CI'[95*'%']*group('[',2.87*','*3.57,']')"`   Then use this in ggplot: `subtitle = parse(text = subtitle)`

Answer (score 3):

An option would be `bquote`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(cyl), wt)) + 
       geom_boxplot() +
       labs(title = "Mean weight:", 
        subtitle = bquote(italic(mu)~"= 3.22,"~CI[95*'%']~"["*"2.87, 3.57"*"]"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks; there are two parts to the question though. Your response solves only the first issue.

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil Thanks, I updated with `bquote` as it seems more direct

Comment: Do you mind also providing a version of the solution that doesn't use `bquote` and is more in line with the existing code in the question?

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil  I would have done that but there is another answer doing that

Comment: It doesn't though. It uses neither `list` nor `paste`, which is important for me because I want to save these expressions as a column in a dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that what you actually care about is that the output looks right, not that plotmath is used. You can use the ggtext package I'm currently developing, which gives you the possibility to use simple markdown/HTML inside of ggplot2. I generally find it much easier to create basic math expressions that way than wrangling with plotmath. And you don't have to work with R expressions at all, the input is always a simple character string.

```r
# this requires the current development versions of ggplot2 and ggtext
# remotes::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
# remotes::install_github("clauswilke/ggtext")

library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(cyl), wt)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(
    title = "Mean weight:",
    subtitle = "*&mu;* = 3.22, CI<sub>95%</sub>[2.87, 3.57]"
  ) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, Claus! I am excited to see that displaying expressions in `ggplot` will get easier in future using `ggtext`. But, currently, this solution doesn't work for me. I would like the solution to stick to the format (as `list` in `character` type column that can be parsed) I've shown because it's the one I need to implement in a package function: https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/blob/8403eff24f117747dc5b5aaad2fcbcdc2565f8b7/R/helpers_ggbetweenstats_graphics.R#L65-L82